# I am having problem connecting to Oracle SQL Developer HR Database

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, archlinux

I have just installed Oracle SQL Developer and I am trying to connect to HR Database for the first time. I tried default username "System" and password "system", "sys", "oracle" but none of them are working. I am using Arch Linux. The Screenshot of the error is attached as well. The Error message is

`Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=ZrfViTiuQUyVFaAIdM2Sxg==)`

[image]

Comment: What Oracle database did you install? There should be connection instructions in the installation guide. Or, have a look at this: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/

Comment: Did you *only* install SQL Developer - or do you have a database to connect to? You might find it useful to read [I have Oracle SQL Developer Installed, Now What?](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/)

Answer (score 2):

What you may know as a distinct "database" in other db products is known as a "schema" in Oracle. You are trying to connect to the HR **schema** rather than the HR **database**.

A schema has an owner (user). To "connect to a schema" you must connect as the schema's owner. So, the Username you should use is `HR` - not `SYSTEM` or anything else. Also, the (default) password for this user is `HR`.

The "Name" field is for the name you want to give to this connection; most likely it should also be HR. It is asking you for a "name" because you are only setting up a **connection** in SQL Developer; you may create different connections, with different settings, to the same schema! In your case though you probably just want one connection to HR for now, and it makes sense to name the connection HR as well.

You may run into additional problems. First, in more recent versions, the Oracle database you download and install may not include the HR schema; you may need to add it after the fact.

Second, you may need to use a Service name rather than a SID - depending on your db version. And you may need to learn about "container" and "pluggable" databases, unless you installed the database with the non-CDB option; the default is the CDB (multi-tenant) option.